# Proof that $a^b>b^a$ if $a<b$ are integers larger or equal to two and $(a,b)\neq (2,3),(2,4)$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I would like a proof that if $a<b$ are integers with $2\leq a,b$ we have $a^b>b^a$ unless $a=2,b=3$ or $a=2,b=4$ . I would like to use as little calculus as possible. Here is my current solution:

Case 1: $a>2$

Fix $a$ and start with $b=a$. notice $a^a=a^a$. Now increase $b$ by $1$ to now get $a^{a+1}>(a+1)^a$. When $a$ is at least three this is true because the left side was multiplied by $a$ and the right side by $(1+\frac{1}{a})^a$.

Since $(1+\frac{1}{a})^a=\sum\limits_{i=0}^a \binom{a}{i} \frac{1}{a^i}$ is the sum of $a+1$ elements all of them smaller than $1$ and the last two terms add $\binom{a}{a-1}\frac{1}{a^{a-1}}+\binom{a}{a}\frac{1}{a^a}=\frac{1}{a^{a-2}}+\frac{1}{a^a}<\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{27}<1$ we conclude the sum is less than $a$. Therefore the inequality holds. Notice that each time we add $1$ to $b$ the left side is multiplied by $a$ and the right by something smaller than $(1+\frac{1}{a})^a$, hence the inequality holds for all $b$ larger than $a$.

Case $a=2$ is the same thing only we check $b=3,4$ by hand and then do something similar.

I am not really happy with the current solution, can we find something simpler? If it can be more combinatorial it would be better. Notice I want as little calculus or inequalities as possible.

Comment: I assume you are talking about integers.

Comment: oops sorry. I'll edit it , although it was already in the title.

Comment: You also switch the meaning of $a,b$ in the title and the body.

Comment: yeah, I just noticed. Fixed.

Comment: Dont you mean$$a^b\ge b^a$$ instead of $$a^b > b^a$$

Comment: Also, not true for $(a,b)=(2,4)$, then $\geq$ but not $>$.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather just add that other exception instead of changing the inequality since it is the only case.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I gave a [related answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/871186/131263) some time ago.

Comment: Well not really since you don't explain how you obtain the result. I appreciate the gesture though

Comment: Is there a quick explanation for why the $\binom{a}{i}\frac{1}{a^i}$ are all no larger than $1$? This seems like an important point that is not obvious.

Comment: Yes. Write the binomial coeficiente so the numerator has i factors on top. a (a-1)....

Comment: Unlike the linked question that this is supposedly a duplicate of, this question is trying to avoid calculus. There is only one answer at the linked question that avoids calculus, and it is along the lines of OP's solution here. OP is looking for something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{N}^a$ as a Cartesian lattice. Consider the collection of paths of length $b$ that

- start at the origin
- grow in legs of length $1$, moving parallel to one of the $a$ axes
- only grow outward from the origin

There are $a^b$ such paths, since for each leg you have $a$ directional options. We can identify a *subset* of these paths whose cardinality is greater than $b^a$, proving the claim.

Let $S$ be the subset of such paths where there is one direction which precisely  $b-a$ of the legs run parallel to, another direction with precisely two legs running parallel, and each of the remaining directions has precisely one parallel leg.

When $b>a+2$, combinatorics tells us that there are $$|S|=\binom{b!}{b-a;2;\overbrace{1;\cdots;1}^{a-2}}\cdot a(a-1)$$ such paths. The multinomial coefficient counts how many paths have $b-a$ legs specifically parallel to the first direction, and two legs specifically parallel to the second. The $a(a-1)$ factor then accounts for all the permutations. Since $b>a+2$, there is no over counting. (We can handle $b=a+1$ and $b=a+2$ similarly, later below).

So $$\begin{align}
a^b
&>\binom{b!}{b-a;2;\overbrace{1;\cdots;1}^{a-2}}\cdot a(a-1)\\
&=b(b-1)\cdots(b-a+1)\cdot\binom{a}{2}\\
\end{align}$$
$b(b-1)\cdots(b-a+1)$ is shy of $b^a$, but the $\binom{a}{2}$ factor should compensate if $a$ is at least $3$. The limit of the ratio $\frac{b(b-1)\cdots(b-a+1)}{b^a}$ is $1$, so this certainly happens for large enough $b$. (It would be nice if we could establish it holds for all $b>a+2$.) Alternatively we could include more paths in $S$ that contribute like $\binom{b!}{b-a-1;2;2;\overbrace{1;\cdots;1}^{a-3}}$ which would cancel the subleading term in $b(b-1)\cdots(b-a+1)$.

When $b=a+2$, $|S|=\binom{b!}{2;2;\overbrace{1;\cdots;1}^{a-2}}\cdot \binom{a}{2}$, and when $b=a+1$, $|S|=\binom{b!}{1;2;\overbrace{1;\cdots;1}^{a-2}}\cdot \binom{a}{1}$. The above parts needs slight modification to compensate.

Comment: I know it's not what you really want, but it's something.

Comment: Well. This is short and simple. So +1. Although it uses more calculus than I want. So I cant accept it.

Comment: @ModdedBear Edited to remove calculus from the part with $b=2$. _Perhaps_ something similar could be engineered for the general case (I'm not sure about that though).

Comment: Completely changed this answer in the direction of a combinatorial argument based on paths of length $b$. See what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $n\geq3$. Then
$$\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}n^{-k}<\sum_{k=0}^n{1\over k!}<e<n\ .$$
It follows that $(n+1)^n<n^{n+1}$, which implies that the function $$n\mapsto n^{1/n}\qquad(n\geq3)$$
is strictly decreasing. This takes care of all cases with $3\leq a<b$. Furthermore one has
$$2^{1/2}=4^{1/4}>n^{1/n}\qquad(n\geq5)\ ,$$
and this settles the remaining cases.