# Find the smallest value of x, for all x real of $(x+1)^{x} ≤ x^{(x+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the smallest value of x, for all x real of $(x+1)^{x} ≤ x^{(x+1)}$

I tried creating a function and evaluating the derivative, but it didn't work. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: use the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871169/find-all-solutions-of-ab-ba

Comment: that is equivalent to $\log (x+1)/(x+1) < \log x / x$. You can then study the function $\log x/x$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116112/find-the-maximum-of-fx-x1-x

Comment: The approx value is x= 2.29317

Comment: How did they get to 2.29? please