# Is there a number that can be represented as $A^B=B^A$ after $16$ , where A and B are 2 distinct real numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

The number $16$ can be represented as $2^4=4^2$. Is there a (real) number after $16$ that can be represented as $A^B=B^A$? Where A and B are two distinct real numbers.I've checked many numbers and I'm convinced that there are  no other numbers with such property, I conjecture that $16$ is the only real number with such property. But maybe I'm wrong. Is it true that $16$ is the only number with such property ? (My question here is much more specific than the other similar question has been posted.)

Comment: Is the number required to be an integer or just a real number $\gt16$?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/xy-yx-for-integers-x-and-y if you just want integers.

Comment: I mean any real numbers : )

Comment: I think my question is much more specific than the other question.

Comment: "Is it true that 16 is the only number with such property ?" - No, at least $1$ and $4$ are also with such property.

Comment: @barakmanos $1^4\ne4^1$. here I mean **2 distinct real numbers A and B**

Comment: @sumpelomiyapah: $1^1=1=1^1,2^2=4=2^2$. And in fact, every positive number has that property.

Comment: (DAA..) **2 distinct real numbers A and B**

Comment: Then you should by the least rephrase that last part of the question (namely, the part where you state "$16$").

Comment: $16=2^4=4^2$. **two distinct real numbers A and B**

Comment: @sumpelomiyapah: This property is not a property of $16$, but a property of the pair $[2,4]$.

Comment: @barakmanos, Number $16$ has a property that.... (you guess it)

Comment: BTW, it is also one of the only two numbers with the property of being equal to the sum of squares of its prime factors ($16=2^2+2^2+2^2+2^2$, and the other one being $27=3^2+3^2+3^2$).

Comment: @barakmanos, That's also nice, but that's out of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are such numbers.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793755/given-that-xy-yx-what-could-x-and-y-be), we know that if $x^y=y^x$ and $x\ne y,$ then $x=a^{1/(a-1)},y=a^{a/(a-1)}$ for some $a\not=1.$
Then we see that $$y\ln x=a^{a/(a-1)}\ln a/(a-1)\gt\ln a\frac{a}{a-1}\gt\ln a,$$ when $a\gt1.$ So if we choose $a\gt16,$ then $x^y=y^x$ so produced will satisfy the requirement.

For example, taking $a=100,$ we see $x=100^{1/99}\cong 1.047615, y=100^{100/99}\cong104.761575$ and $x^y=y^x\cong130.726237\gt16.$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks !!, this is EXACTLY the answer I'm looking for ! : D

Comment: You're welcome. It is a pleasure to ponder upon such a question. :D

Comment: Quoting the answer: "However, I'm going to go a step further.  I will say that I want my solution $(x,y)$ of $x^y = y^x$ to be of the form $(x,ax)$ so that $y = ax$ for some value $a$.  Furthermore, I'll assume that $x \neq y$ so that $a \neq 1$ (of course, $x = y$ is always a solution if $x^x$ is defined). With that, we have...
"

Comment: Does this kind of number has been named by someone ? Partner numbers ? : )

Comment: Well, I don't know much about them, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The power can be larger than $16$.

Consider the set of points on the plane satisfying the equation

$$x^y=y^x$$

[image]

You see that those points form a union of two curves: the line $x=y$ and the more interesting part.

By implicit differentiation we get that on that other curve we have
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(x\ln y-y)}{x(y\ln x-x)}.
$$

Using that and logarithmic differentiation we get that on that curve

$$
\frac d{dx}\,y^x=y^x\left[\ln y+\frac{x\ln y-y}{y\ln x-x}\right].
$$

Plugging in $x=4, y=2$ shows that at the point $(x,y)=(4,2)$ we arrive at

$$\frac{d(y^x)}{dx}=\frac{16 (1-\ln2\ln4)}{2-\ln4}\approx1.019.$$

Therefore when $x$ is a little bit larger than $4$ the power $y^x=x^y$ will be a little bit larger than $16$.

I hazard a guess that along that curve $y^x=x^y$ attains a local minimum $e^e\approx 15.15$ at the point $x=y=e$. The formula for the derivative breaks down there (which may explain why Mathematica left a tiny gap there in the above figure).