# How can we find x for x^n = n^x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Find values of x such that $x^n=n^x$
Here, n $\in$ I.

One solution will remain **x=n**
But i want to find if any more solutions can exist

$$x^n=n^x$$

Comment: There's a whole Wikipedia page for this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_x%CA%B8_%3D_y%CB%A3

Comment: search "$a^b=b^a$ and you will see the answer

Comment: I in this stands for integer

Comment: Why does Wolfram alpha not find the three real solutions (only as integer solutions , $2$ is displayed). https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex%3Dx%5E2

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/793755/11619) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1858105/11619).

Answer (score 2):

I love this question! I first saw it while in sixth form (I'm from London that means when I was 18)

The first thing we can do is to try and get just x on one side and just y on the other side. Heres what we can do using logs: 
 
If x<sup>y</sup>  = y<sup>x</sup> then we have to have log(x<sup>y</sup> ) = log(y<sup>x</sup>) as the log function is a bijection.  
I.e:
x<sup>y</sup>  = y<sup>x</sup> $\iff$ log(x<sup>y</sup> ) = log(y<sup>x</sup>). 
 
(Please note that when I write log I mean the natural based log, you may be used to seeing ln instead but I mean the very same thing.) 
 Now we can use the following log rule : log(a<sup>b</sup> )=b* log(a) to get 
x<sup>y</sup>  = y<sup>x</sup>  $\iff$ y* log(x) = x*log(y) 
 Dividing both sides of our RHS by x *y yeilds: 
x<sup>y</sup>  = y<sup>x</sup>  $\iff$ $\frac{log(x)}{x}   = \frac{log(y)}{y}     $ 
 Perfect! We now have just x on one side and just y on the other. Lets call f(t) the function $\frac{log(t)}{t}$ so we know that the if any pair x and y solve x<sup>y</sup>  = y<sup>x</sup> then we MUST also have f(x) = f(y) and likewise if we find any pair x and y such that f(x) = f(y) then we also know that x<sup>y</sup>  = y<sup>x</sup>. 
 
 Onto finding soloutions of f(x) = f(y). 
  I will highly encourage you to graph this function either by hand or using something like Desmos and from that you'll be able to nearly get all thats left but heres a short summary of what you'll find: 
 1) The function tends to negative infinity as t tends to 0. 
 2) The function tends to 0 as t tends to infinity 
 3)There is a turning point (global maximum) of this function at t = e (this "little fact" is actually a great proof of why e<sup>x</sup>  > x<sup>e</sup> for all x)
 4) The function is strictly increasing up to e and then strictly decreasing after it. 
 1) and 2) can be seen from a simple look at limits and 3) and 4) come from a quick examination of its derivative.  
 
So if we are after pairs of numbers x and y such that f(x) = f(y) we know that one of them needs to be less than e and one of them greater than e. If its only integer soloutions you are after, great! You only have 2 integers to check as the only ones less than e are 1 and 2. Its quite quick to see that 1 is not going to be helpfull at all as 1<sup>x</sup>  = 1 and x<sup>1</sup>  = x so your only soloution if you chose x = 1 will be y =1 . Trying x =2 is more more fruitfull, a little checking and guessing gives x = 2 and y =4 a soloution to this, there are also no other y for x=2 as our f is strictly decreasing beyond e. 
 Thus the only integer soloutions to x<sup>y</sup>  = y<sup>x</sup> is x =2 and y=4 (well you can have x =4 and y=2 but thats the same thing!) 
 If you are after non integer soloutions you have a few options, you can pick any x you want, as there will always be a y with the same value of f and then using some method of approximation the root to f(t)-f(x) 
 
 I hope this helped :) 
 Oskar

Comment: Please make use of [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) MathJax tutorial so that you can typeset equations and make them more readable.

Answer (score 0):

*Welcome to the wonderful world of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) !*

If, on the search bar, you just type *Lambert*, you will find almost 3000 entries.

This function $W(z)$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions but it is rather simple since it is "just" the solution of the equation 
$$z=W(z)\,e^{W(z)}$$

Because of lack of time, I let you the pleasure of discovering it in the linked page. In the real domain, $W(z)$ is defined as long as $z \geq -\frac 1e$ and it has two branches, the secondary one existing when $-\frac 1e \leq z \lt 0$.

To make the story short, for the equation
$$x^n=n^x$$ beside the trivial $x=n$ potentially exist two solutions given by
$$x_1=-\frac{n }{\log (n)}W_0\left(-\frac{\log (n)}{n}\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad -\frac{n }{\log (n)}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (n)}{n}\right)$$

Since you want $n$ to be a positive integer, I give you below a list of values of the $W_0(.)$ since the other one cannot exist for natural numbers.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x \\
 2 & 2.00000 \\
 3 & 2.47805 \\
 4 & 2.00000 \\
 5 & 1.76492 \\
 6 & 1.62424 \\
 7 & 1.53014 \\
 8 & 1.46250 \\
 9 & 1.41138 \\
 10 & 1.37129 \\
 20 & 1.19624 \\
 30 & 1.13767 \\
 40 & 1.10754 \\
 50 & 1.08893 \\
 60 & 1.07620 \\
 70 & 1.06690 \\
 80 & 1.05977 \\
 90 & 1.05412 \\
 100 & 1.04952
\end{array}
\right)$$

To check it, use your pocket calculator for $n=50$ and $x=1.08893$

$$1.08893^{50}=70.7943\qquad \text{and} \qquad 50^{1.08893}=70.8043$$