# Solving $a^b = b^a$ for $a,b \in \Bbb N$ where $a,b$ are distinct

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

While preparing for the Putnam math competition my teacher listed the following problem:
 Solving $a^b = b^a$ for $a,b \in \Bbb N$ where $a,b$ are distinct. I suspect the answer is that there is only one solution: $a=2$ and $b=4$. Now I start with the obvious that $b*ln(a) = a*ln(b)$ and clearly since a,b are distinct then either $a<b$ or $a>b$. Now suppose $b>a$ then $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{lna}{lnb}$  . Now here is where I am stuck. Any hints or ideas are much appreciated.

Edit: Upon more thought it seems that a and b most both be even or odd since otherwise $a^b$ would be odd while $b^a$ would be even and vice versa.

Comment: $a,b$ have the same prime factors

Comment: Look at $\frac{\ln x}{x}$. Where is it increasing and where is it decreasing?  Then the answer for integers will fall out. I am not writing an answer because  I am sure I have seen the problem (more than once) on MSE.

Comment: @AndréNicolas it is increasing from $(0,e)$ and decreasing from $(e, \infty)$

Comment: That's right, so we can get $x^y=y^x$ with $x\ne y$ only with $x$ before $e$ and $y$ after, or the other way. Thus with integers the only candidates for the smaller one are $x=1$ or $x=2$, and $x=2$ works.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793755/given-that-xy-yx-what-could-x-and-y-be/793769#793769) provides an answer, albeit not the most direct possible answer.

Comment: You can find an entire sequence of solutions for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ if you assume that $a=kb$.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you want solutions in $\mathbb{N}$. Nevermind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A trivial answer would be $a=b$.

For other solutions, we can assume $a>b$ without loss of generality.

Consider $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^b$. Because $a^b=b^a$, we have $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^b = b^{a-b}$. Note that $b^{a-b}$ has to be a natural number because $a-b \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^b \in \mathbb{N}$.

This allows one to write $a=c b$ for some $c \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence $a^b=b^a$ becomes

$$(cb)^b=b^{cb}$$

which implies

$$b=c^{\frac{1}{c-1}}.$$

This yields a solution $b \in \mathbb{N}$ if and only if $c=2$. Furthermore, this results in $b=2$, $a=4$.

Comment: why can you write a = cb for some $c \in \Bbb N$

Comment: Because $(\frac{a}{b})^b \in \mathbb N$, we have $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb N$ as well. Thus, $a$ can be written as $a = c b$.

Comment: I should add to clarify that $b^{cb} = (b^{c-1}b)^{b} \implies c = b^{c-1} \implies b = c^{1/(c-1)}$ and that $c$ has to be larger than 1.