# Integer solutions to $a^b = b^a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm sure that throughout the history of mathematics the problem to find solutions of the equation $$a^b = b^a$$
has been raised. The only solution I have found off the top of my head is $$ a = 2, b = 4$$
My question is whether this problem has a name and it it has some relevance in mathematics

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793755/given-that-xy-yx-what-could-x-and-y-be/793769#793769)