# $x^y = y^x$ Closed form solution??

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I looked and could not find... How can I show the solutions for $x^y = y^x$?

There (as far as I can tell) are three curves satisfying this. One is $x=y$, one curves through $(2,4) (4,2) (e,e)$ and goes asymptotic in the $++$ and $+-$ quadrants and its mirror image reflected across $x=y$.

But it is not easy to find a closed form expression for the solutions...at least not for me. Thanks

Comment: As I explain in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/793769/81360), the solution space can be parametrized as $(a^{1/(a-1)},a^{a/(a-1)})$ where $a \neq 1$ (with $a > 0$, if we're looking for real numbers).

Comment: Wikimedia has [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%9F_x%5Ey%3Dy%5Ex.png) (and [as a permanent link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%9F_x%5Ey%3Dy%5Ex.png&oldid=216613018)).

Answer (score 1):

This requires the Lambert W function.

$$y^x=x^y$$

$$y^{1/y}=x^{1/x}$$

Take the reciprocal of both sides:

$$(1/y)^{1/y}=(1/x)^{1/x}$$

$$\frac1y=e^{W\left(-\frac{\ln(x)}x\right)}$$

> $$\large y=e^{-W\left(-\frac{\ln(x)}x\right)}$$

If we take the $W_0$ branch, we get $y=x$.  If we take the $W_{-1}$ branch, we get the other weird looking line.

Comment: And so I go down the Lambert function rabbit hole.... gracias

Comment: XD your welcome @Thefracman