# If we have $\dfrac{\log y}{y} = \dfrac{\log x}{x} $, then is it necessary for $x=y$?

Tags: logarithms, radicals

The actual question which I was solving was proving ${{\sqrt[x]{x}^{\sqrt[x]{x}}}^\sqrt[x]{x}}^{...}=x$

Taking the expression equal to some variable,

$\rightarrow{{\sqrt[x]{x}^{\sqrt[x]{x}}}^\sqrt[x]{x}}^{...}=y$

$\rightarrow(\sqrt[x]{x})^y=y$

$\rightarrow \sqrt[x]{x} = \sqrt[y]{y}$

$\rightarrow x^y = y^x$

or,

$\rightarrow \dfrac{\log x}{x} = \dfrac{\log y}{y}$

Does this imply that $x=y$ ?

Comment: what about $4^2=2^4$?

Comment: I know that, that made me a little confuse - See [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-sqrt-x-x-sqrt-x-x-sqrt-x-x-sqrt-x-x-sqrt-x-x-sqrt-x-x-cdots-x-true), I see many answers here according to which $\dfrac{log x}{x} = \dfrac{log y}{y} \implies x=y$

Comment: The function $f(x)={\log x\over x}$ is $0$ at $x=1$, positive for $x\gt1$ and tends back to $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/793755/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for linking the question. May I know how did you find it? I searched my question for around 30 minutes on internet but didn't find any satisfied solution and at last I posted it here.

Comment: @ProThala: With [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cdfrac%7B%5Clog%20y%7D%7By%7D%20%3D%20%5Cdfrac%7B%5Clog%20x%7D%7Bx%7D%24). See also [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given that $x^y=y^x$, what could $x$ and $y$ be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793755/given-that-xy-yx-what-could-x-and-y-be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we go back a step to the original equation, we have

$\sqrt[x]{x}^{\sqrt[x]{x}^{\sqrt[x]{x}^{\sqrt[x]{x}^{...}}}}=x$

only where $t=x$ is a stable or perhaps marginally stable fixed point of the mapping $t\to\sqrt[x]{x}^t$. Perturbation analysis reveals that the fixed point is stable for $|\ln(x)<1|$ and marginally stable for $|\ln(x)=1|$. It turns out that with $t_1=\sqrt[x]{x}$ convergence holds at the marginally stable points, so the equality holds for $x=\exp[\exp(a+i\theta)]$ where $a\le0$.

For instance, if we use $\sqrt2=\sqrt[4]{4}$ as our base, then the "infinite tetration", as it is technically called, will be $2\approx\exp[\exp(\color{blue}{-0.367}+i0)]$ and not $4\approx\exp[\exp(\color{red}{+0.327}+i0)]$.

Answer (score 4):

In general we have that

$$f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$$

only for [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) that is for example for strictly increasing or decreasing function which is not the case for $f(x)=\dfrac{\log x}{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Note that
$$
\frac{\log 4}{4} = \frac{\log 2}{2}
$$
since $\log 4 = 2\log 2$.