# $x^y = y^x$ what is $y$?

Tags: lambert-w

So today I came across an [answer on MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/793760/983206). I read it and found it well explained. But I stuck on a step where the user write "Solve using the properties of $W$ function". I don't know what property the user used.

What I know about Lambert $W$ function is that, $W(x) = f^{-1} (x)$, where $f(x) = x\cdot e^x$.

Can anyone solve the question or just tell me what the property the answerer used in the question which I have linked to you?

Comment: I'm not sure that really helps, since values of $W$ aren't really computable in any sort of closed form anyway.  It's sort of a cheat to say "oh just use $W$ to get your answers."

Comment: @amWhy that's the question OP is asking clarification for.

Comment: @amWhy did you even read my question? Or just you read the title and voted to close it?

Comment: The property of the $W$ function is that $a = W(b)$ if and only if $ae^a = b$ (with $a \ge -1$ and $b \ge -\dfrac 1e$). The linked question uses $a = -\dfrac{y\log(x)}{x}$ and $b = -\dfrac{\log(x)}{x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step in question is how do the properties of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), give us the following
$$-\dfrac{y\log(x)}{x}\exp\left(-\dfrac{y\log(x)}{x}\right) = -\dfrac{\log(x)}{x}\implies-xy\log(x) = \operatorname{W}\left(-\dfrac{\log(x)}{x}\right).$$

There is actually a typo in the [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/793760/983206), (which I corrected), the desired result should be
$$-\dfrac{y\log(x)}{x}\exp\left(-\dfrac{y\log(x)}{x}\right)= -\frac{\log(x)}{x}\implies= -\frac{y\log(x)}{x}  = \operatorname{W}\left(-\dfrac{\log(x)}{x}\right).$$

Here we will use the fact that $$z = we^w \iff w = W(z).$$

We first make the substitutions
$$s = -\frac{y\log(x)}{x},\qquad z = -\frac{\log(x)}{x},$$

and rewrite the first equation as $se^{s} =z.$

Using the noted property of $W$, then, we can rewrite this as $s = W(z)$, which reversing our substitutions gives:

$$-\frac{y\log(x)}{x} = W\left(-\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right).$$

Answer (score -1):

as @Randall mentioned, using the $W$ function is really just putting a name on it, only more complex maths programs are actually going to return values for you. That said:
$$y^x=x^y\\
y^{1/y}=x^{1/x}\\
\frac1y\ln y=\frac1x\ln x$$
now say $y=e^{-u}$ so:
$$ue^u=-\frac1x\ln x\\
u=W_k\left(-\frac1x\ln x\right)\\
y=\exp\left[-W_k\left(-\frac1x\ln x\right)\right]$$
where $k$ denotes the branch of the $W$ function